# Gmail app - increase font size when sending

Tags: gmail, fonts

I'm not asking about how to increase font size of emails I have received or how to zoom in those emails.

I am asking about how increase font size of emails that I compose and send in the Gmail Android app (the new version that supports bold, colors and stuff).

In a desktop computer, there is an option for that:

[image]

Is there an option for such in the Gmail Android app?

Comment: I just discovered that there is [a Gmail app update that supports rich text compose](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2016/02/productivity-at-your-fingertips.html).  I can't seem to get it on my device -- it must be for Marshmallow only?  In any case, I'm not sure if there's a way to change the font size and I've removed my answer.

Comment: @MatthewRead thanks ^-^ I think the Gmail app update is related to Samsung or android updates. I don't think I had rich text compose before my phone installed updates

Comment: The rich text compose app update for Android does not include font size. It only allows changes to bold, italic, underline and text color.